# Pallate for Native Blockchain Currency

Tags: pallet, assets, tcurrency

In my Blockchain app, I want to add my own native currency. For extended Features of my application Users will be rewarded and they will receive coin for that. The users will receive the reward in real time upon their action in the application.
Is there any existing pallet that will help me to implement this function on my app.

Answer (score 0):

Native currency => `pallet-balances`

Rewards => `pallet-tips` (tightly coupled to `pallet-treasury`)